# How to include Enum in Dart class?

Tags: dart, enums

I have defined enum like:

```
enum Status {
 done,
 current,
 future
}
```

I want to include this enum inside the class which is defined below.
Both the enum and class are in same file.

The enum is defined outside of the class because multiple classes should be able to use it.

When using the enum vscode is giving me an error `Status not defined`

```
class WeekDay extends StatelessWidget {
 final int day;
 final Status status;
 const WeekDay({this.day, this.status});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container();
 }
}
```

How do we import Enum in class in Dart?

Comment: Have you imported the file containing the `enum`?

Comment: i guess no! How do we import?

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the files your are depending on like the following (if e.g. status and weekday are in the same folder):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for the silly question.
It Was `VSCODE` problem,

The error was gone after restarting the `vscode`.

The above code works perfectly fine.